# uitableview separator above content and not at the bottom

Tags: ios, uitableview

look at my table view please

[image]

as you see, the separator (and for some reason) becomes above the content,

how can i make it at the button example of each cell

i didn't add any custom code or anything to the interface builder, i just change the font of the cells to my custom font.

this is a screenshot of the simulator, and on my iphone it is the same problem appear

Comment: The separator is at the bottom of the cell. Can you explain yourself better ? Is it the inset that disturbs you ?

Comment: @shannoga no it is not at the bottom, look at sunday and the date bellow it, both at the same cell. shouldn't it be at the bottom?

Comment: @shannoga i have constrains for all these arrows to make them center on the y axis. when i click on the cell i can see 100% that this separator is not at the bottom of the cell

Comment: so u want to move the separator to right side ?

Comment: @Mr.T no i want it to be at the bottom of each cell

Comment: @sarah I have answered your question

Comment: @shannoga sorry for being late

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok

It looks like your cell height is too small, You should increase the cell size. To test if I am right set the cell content view **clipSubviews** to true, you should see that your views are cropped.